# Android unable to get object array from redux

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-redux

I was new to react native, now i face a problem to retrieve object array data from redux. Same code working on ios simulator but on android emulator fail `(TypeError:undefined is not an object)`

```
onPressme = () => {
    alert(this.props.groupddl.groupDdl[0].label)
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        groupddl: state.attendanceReducers
    };
}
```

Reducer declare as `groupDdl = []`

Same code working on ios simulator, fail on android. Any solution will be appreciate. thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your state and/or the initial state for the `attendanceReducers` reducer?

Comment: Why there is tag of **android** **ios**

Answer (score 0):

I think this error happen because you try to accesss `groupDdl[0].label` while your reducer `groupDdl = []`

Change your logic to check `groupDdl[0]` exists & if so display your alert as below

```
onPressme = () => {
    alert(this.props.groupddl.groupDdl[0] && this.props.groupddl.groupDdl[0].label)
}
```